# how to pass script variable in <util:remotePaginate/>

Tags: javascript, grails

i need to pass javascript variable with 
like this

```
<util:remotePaginate controller="myControl" action="search" params="[a:serchForm//here is javascript variable]" total="${totalVideo}" update="dataTableDiv" max="2"/>


<script>
var serchForm = JSON.stringify($("#formid").serializeArray());
</script>
```

is there any way to do like this

Comment: If you have a look at the grails remoteFunction tag, this allows you to pass javascript variables ( params: '\'bookName=\' + this.value'), perhaps the same can be done with remotePaginate tags? (http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/ref/Tags/remoteFunction.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by creating hidden filed on you gsp and assign the value. in your case your code looks some thing like this

```
<g:hiddenField name="formid" value="" />

<script>
var serchForm = JSON.stringify($("#formid").serializeArray());
$('#formid').val(serchForm);
</script>

<util:remotePaginate controller="myControl" action="search" params="['\'formid=\'+formid']" total="${totalVideo}" update="dataTableDiv" max="2"/>
```

refer: https://github.com/amitjain1982/remote-pagination

hope this helps.

Regards
Motilal